# Visual Studio 2013 on .NET Framework 4.5.2

Tags: windows-7, .net-framework, visual-studio-2013

I am about to install Visual Studio 2013 (includes Update 4) which comes with .NET Framework 4.5.1.

My Windows 7 OS has .NET Framework 4.5.2 installed.

How will the Visual Studio installer deal with this? Will it leave the existing Framework 4.5.2 intact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should. Among other things .NET related I'm seeing 4.5 Multi-Targeting Pack, 4.5 SDK, 4.5.1 Multi-Targeting Pack and 4.5.1 SDK in addition to 4.5.2.

Comment: I can confirm you are right. I installed VS2013 and the existing .NET 4.5.2 Framework installation was left untouched.  Incidentally, VS2013 can't target 4.5.2 unless the appropriate multi-targeting pack is installed afterwards. But it can target 4.5/4.5.1 out-of-the-box and that's all I need.